# Set the cursor to end of sentence in Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am coding in c# to convert a PDF document to MS Word and format word document as per my need.

Can anyone suggest me how to

1. Set cursor focus to end of each sentence and Hit enter at end of each sentence.
2. Select and format only first alphabet of every paragraph.

Here is the code I am using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedFiles; i++)
{

    inFileName = openFile.SafeFileNames[i];
    outFileName = inFileName;
    pos = inFileName.LastIndexOf('.');
    if (pos > 0)
        outFileName = outFileName.Substring(0, pos);
    outFileName += ".doc";

    //outFileName = savePDFFile.FileName;

    //Convert(openFile.SafeFileNames[i], outFileName);
    Convert(cPath + inFileName, cPath + outFileName);

    Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    //OBJECTS OF FALSE AND TRUE
    Object oTrue = true;
    Object oFalse = false;
    //Create word document  


    Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();
    Object oTemplatePath = cPath + outFileName;

    oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

    #region Replace Keyword
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, "   ", " ");
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, ". ", ".");
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, " . ", ".");
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, " .", ".");
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, "-", " – ");
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, ",", " ,");
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, " , ", " ,");
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, " -", "-");
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, " - ", "-");
    this.FindAndReplace(oWord, "- ", "-");
    #endregion Replace Keyword
    Word.Range rng = null;
    if (oWordDoc.Sentences.Count > 0)
    {
        object startLocation = oWordDoc.Sentences[1].Start;
        object endLocation = oWordDoc.Sentences[1].End;
        // Supply a Start and End value for the Range. 
        rng = oWordDoc.Range(ref startLocation, ref endLocation);
        // Select the Range.
        rng.Select();
    }
    object missing = Missing.Value;
    object what = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;
    object which = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast;
    oWordDoc.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref missing, ref missing);
    for (int j = 0; j < oWordDoc.Sentences.Count; j++)
    {
        //oWordDoc.Sentences[j].Text = oWordDoc.Sentences[j].Text.ToString() + "\n";
    }
    // add header
    foreach (Section section in oWordDoc.Sections)
    {
        Range headerRange = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
        headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
        headerRange.Font.Size = 12;
        headerRange.Font.Name = "Ariel";

        if (rng != null)
            headerRange.Text = rng.Text.Trim();
    }
    rng.Text = "";
    object findStr = "rr"; //sonething to find
    while (oWord.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findStr))  //found...
    {
        //change font and format of matched words
        oWord.Selection.Font.Name = "Tahoma"; //change font to Tahoma
        oWord.Selection.Font.Size = 48;
        oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle;
        //oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0.0F;
        oWord.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed;  //change color to red
    }
    oWordDoc.Content.Font.Name = "Franklin Gothic Book";
    oWordDoc.Content.Font.Size = 11.5F;
    oWordDoc.Content.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;
    //oWordDoc.Content.Start = 0;
    oWordDoc.ShowGrammaticalErrors = false;
    oWordDoc.ShowSpellingErrors = false;
    //oWordDoc.Content.Sections.First
    oWordDoc.SaveAs(cPath + outFileName);
    progressBar1.Value = (((i + 1) * 100) / selectedFiles);
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code.  It is too much to expect people to read.  You will be more likely to get quality answers if you reduce it to the smallest working example.  So I would image the stuff about font sizes could be deleted.  We don't need to read that.

Comment: I believe it is just fine. As long as it is reproducible. I have seen longer ones here

Answer (score 1):

You can use [InsertParagraphAfter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.insertparagraphafter.aspx) function to add new line after each sentence.

Something like:

```
       int count = oWordDoc.Sentences.Count;
       for(int i=1; i<=count;i++)
       {
          object startLocation = oWordDoc.Sentences[i].Start;
          object endLocation = oWordDoc.Sentences[i].End;
          // Supply a Start and End value for the Range. 
          rng = oWordDoc.Range(ref startLocation, ref endLocation);
          // Select the Range.
          rng.Select();
          rng.InsertParagraphAfter();
       }
```

Comment: thanks, it work fine enough,But i am in search that THERE SHOULD BE NO SPACE AFTER LAST WORD OF EACH SENTENCE. THERE SHOULD BE A SINGLE ENTER AFTER EVERY SENTENCE....Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Use Range.Move method to move cursor between sentence either start or end of the sentence.

try bellow code.

```
oRange.Move(WdUnits.wdSentence, -1);
```

If it helps please mark answer as positive.

Thanks